# How to pass map values to other files

Tags: go

**file1**

```
func loopFunc() {
    m := make(map[int]net.Conn)
    for i := 1; i < 10000; i++ {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        m[i] = c
    }
    iWantMaps(m)
}
```

**file2**
doesn't exist yet,  but a random assigning to a value from the map will do as an example

```
func iWantMaps(m) {
    something := m[1]
}
```

This is my project structure:

```
+/pkg
+-->file1
+-->file2
```

Consider a for loop that constantly updates a map in file1.
I'm trying to either:

- transfer the whole map from file1 to a function in file2
- be able to retrieve keys and values from the map in file1 from a function in file2.

Comment: Please show your code.  Go organizes code by package, not by file, so if your files are in the same package (it seems they are), there's nothing preventing you from doing this. But it's hard to offer specific suggestions without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Tried to add as you asked

Comment: Thanks for the update.  But if file2 doesn't exist yet, then what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Edited for your comfort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but from my understanding, you want to ensure that the function in the second file can access the map from the function in the first file, correct?

For simplicity, I will call **fn1** the function that lives in **file 1**, and **fn2** the function that lives in **file 2**.

The fact that they are not in different files should not affect anything, as long as they have access to each other. One alternative is to declare your map in the parent function (the function that calls both your **fn1** and **fn2**) and then pass this map as an argument for both functions. For example:

```
func fn1(sessionMap map[int]int) {
    for i := 1; i < 10000; i++ {
        // do some work here
        sessionMap[i] = i
    }
}

func fn2(sessionMap map[int]int) {
    for i := 1; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Println(sessionMap[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    sessionMap := make(map[int]int)
    fn1(sessionMap)
    fn2(sessionMap)
}
```

If, however, **fn2** is being called by **fn1**, you can declare the map in **fn1** and pass it to **fn2** like this:

```
func fn1() {
    sessionMap := make(map[int]int)

    for i := 1; i < 10000; i++ {
        // do some work here
        sessionMap[i] = i
    }

    fn2(sessionMap)
}

func fn2(sessionMap map[int]int) {
    for i := 1; i < 10000; i++ {
        fmt.Println(sessionMap[i])
    }
}


func main() {
    fn1()
}
```

**fn1** and **fn2** can both live in separate or the same files.

Cheers

Comment: A perfect solution for my struggle, thank you so much!